# Proving that $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le\int_{-1}^{1}\arctan (x)dx\le \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

I have the following question:

> Prove that: $$-\frac{\pi}{2}\le\int_{-1}^{1}\arctan (x)dx\le \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

---

I know that the function is odd and therefore, the given integral is 0, and the inequality therefore holds. However, showing and proving this theorem in which the integral of an odd function from $-a$ to $a$ is zero, isn't what this question intended to. It is likely in this question that we should show that via Darboux's sums, or Riemann sums. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to deal with such trigonometric sums. Hence, I will be glad to get some help with this question, and I am sorry that I haven't written an attempt for this question. Thanks!

Comment: $$
\left| {\int_{ - 1}^1 {\arctan xdx} } \right| \le \int_{ - 1}^1 {\left| {\arctan x} \right|dx}  \le \int_{ - 1}^1 {\frac{\pi }{4}dx}  = \frac{\pi }{4}\int_{ - 1}^1 {dx}  = \frac{\pi }{2}.
$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x\in[-1,1]$, $-\frac\pi4\leqslant\arctan(x)\leqslant\frac\pi4$, and therefore$$2\times\left(-\frac\pi4\right)\leqslant\int_{-1}^1\arctan x\,\mathrm dx\leqslant2\times\frac\pi4.$$

Comment: How do I know your first claim, when the function is bounded by $\frac{\pi}{4}$, and how do I know the inequality of the integral you gave. Can you elaborate more about the steps you made?

Comment: Since$$x\in\left[-\frac\pi4,\frac\pi4,\right]\implies\tan(x)\in[-1,1],$$we have$$x\in[-1,1]\implies\arctan(x)\in\left[-\frac\pi4,\frac\pi4,\right].$$And if $m,M\in\Bbb R$ are such that$$(\forall x\in[a,b]):m\leqslant f(x)\leqslant M,$$then$$m(b-a)\leqslant\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx\leqslant M(b-a).$$

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think to use this theorem.